# MSXML2 restful API call returns no data on Windows Embedded Standard

Tags: rest, api, msxml

I use the following code to consume restful APIs inside a PowerBASIC windows application which returns lists of contacts and tickets for a customer.  The trace code produces good results on my Windows 10 Pro system.

When I run the same query using POSTman on the same Windows Embedded Standard Service Pack 1 system t works fine.

On the Windows Embedded Standard Service Pack 1 system, I get Response 0

```
Here is the trace results on WIndows Embedeed SP1, do not get any tickets.
15:58:49>TEAMSUPP_GETCUSTKTS URLPath=</xml/Customers/1103428/Tickets> 
15:58:49>TeamSupportAPI Open bstrURL=https://app.teamsupport.com/api/xml/Customers/1103428/Tickets 
15:58:49>TeamSupportAPI Send Verb=GET bstrURL=https://app.teamsupport.com/api/xml/Customers/1103428/Tickets XML= 
15:58:49>TeamSupportAPI Response=<<> 0<>> 
15:58:49>TEAMSUPP_GETCUSTKTS Response=<<> 0<>> 
15:58:49>TeamSupportAPI Open bstrURL=https://app.teamsupport.com/api/xml/Customers/1103428/Contacts 
15:58:49>TeamSupportAPI Send Verb=GET bstrURL=https://app.teamsupport.com/api/xml/Customers/1103428/Contacts XML= 
15:58:49>TeamSupportAPI Response=<<> 0<>> 

Results on Windows 10 Pro system I get Response=<<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
15:52:02>TeamSupportAPI Open bstrURL=https://app.teamsupport.com/api/xml/Customers/1103428/Tickets 
15:52:02>TeamSupportAPI Send Verb=GET bstrURL=https://app.teamsupport.com/api/xml/Customers/1103428/Tickets XML= 
15:52:12>TeamSupportAPI Response=<<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Tickets>
  <Ticket>
...
    <Tags />
  </Ticket>
</Tickets><> 200<>OK> 


15:52:12>TeamSupportAPI Open bstrURL=https://app.teamsupport.com/api/xml/Customers/1103428/Contacts 
15:52:12>TeamSupportAPI Send Verb=GET bstrURL=https://app.teamsupport.com/api/xml/Customers/1103428/Contacts XML= 
15:52:12>TeamSupportAPI Response=<<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Contacts>
  <Contact>
    <Email>averspizza@msn.com</Email>
    <FirstName>Brad </FirstName>
    <ContactID>3824219</ContactID>
    <MiddleName />
    <LastName>Randall</LastName>
    <Title />
    <IsActive>True</IsActive>
    <LastLogin>5/9/2016 1:31 PM</LastLogin>
    <LastActivity>5/9/2016 12:31 PM</LastActivity>
    <LastPing />
    <IsPortalUser>False</IsPortalUser>
    <PrimaryGroupID />
    <InOffice>False</InOffice>
    <InOfficeComment />
    <ActivatedOn>5/9/2016 1:31 PM</ActivatedOn>
    <DeactivatedOn />
    <OrganizationID>1103428</OrganizationID>
    <Organization>Avers North</Organization>
    <DateCreated>5/9/2016 1:31 PM</DateCreated>
    <DateModified>5/9/2016 1:31 PM</DateModified>
    <CreatorID>3526274</CreatorID>
    <ModifierID>3526274</ModifierID>
    <DisableOrganizationTicketsViewOnPortal>False</DisableOrganizationTicketsViewOnPortal>
    <PortalViewOnly>False</PortalViewOnly>
    <BlockInboundEmail>False</BlockInboundEmail>
    <EMail2 />
    <isar>False</isar>
  </Contact>
</Contacts><> 200<>OK> 



FUNCTION TeamSupportAPI(BYVAL Verb AS STRING, BYVAL XMLString AS STRING, BYVAL URLPath AS STRING) AS STRING
   LOCAL objHTTP AS IXMLHTTPRequest
   LOCAL bstrURL AS WSTRING
   LOCAL bstrResponse AS WSTRING
   LOCAL vXML AS VARIANT
   vXML = XMLString
   objHTTP = NEWCOM "Msxml2.ServerXMLHTTP.6.0"
   IF ISNOTHING(objHTTP) THEN
     IF PTDebugCfgVal(%PTDEBUGPyriTeamSupportApi) THEN WriteDebugLogFile("TeamSupportAPI objHTTP is Nothing")
     EXIT FUNCTION
   END IF
   ' Opens an HTTP connection to an HTTP resource
   bstrURL = "https://app.teamsupport.com/api"
   '15:20:00>Open bstrURL=https://app.teamsupport.com/api/xml/Tickets//Actions    
   bstrURL = bstrURL + URLPath
   objHTTP.Open Verb, bstrURL, 0, $orgID, $apiToken
   ' Sends an HTTP request to the HTTP server
   IF PTDebugCfgVal(%PTDEBUGPyriTeamSupportApi) THEN WriteDebugLogFile("TeamSupportAPI Open bstrURL="+bstrURL)
   objHTTP.SetRequestHeader "Authorization", "Basic " + Get_Base64_Encode($orgID & ":" & $apiToken)
   objHTTP.SetRequestHeader "Cache-Control", "max-age=0"
   objHTTP.SetRequestHeader "Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*"
   objHTTP.SetRequestHeader "Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "*"
   objHTTP.SetRequestHeader "Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "POST, GET, OPTIONS, DELETE, PUT"
   '15:20:00>Send Verb=POST bstrURL=https://app.teamsupport.com/api/xml/Tickets//Actions XML=<Ticket><TicketStatusID>251029</TicketStatusID>
   '<TicketTypeID>41053</TicketTypeID><TicketTypeName>Support</TicketTypeName><Name>test</Name><Description><![CDATA[<p>test</p>
   If PTDebugCfgVal(%PTDEBUGPyriTeamSupportApi) THEN WriteDebugLogFile("TeamSupportAPI Send Verb="+Verb+" bstrURL="+bstrURL+" XML="+VARIANT$(vXML))
   objHTTP.Send(vXML)
   bstrResponse = "x"
   IF objHTTP.Status = 200 THEN ' HTTP_STATUS_OK=200
      bstrResponse = objHTTP.ResponseText + "<>" + STR$(objHTTP.Status) + "<>" + objHTTP.StatusText
   ELSE
      bstrResponse = objHTTP.ResponseText + "<>" + STR$(objHTTP.Status) + "<>" + objHTTP.StatusText
   END IF
   IF PTDebugCfgVal(%PTDEBUGPyriTeamSupportApi) THEN WriteDebugLogFile("TeamSupportAPI Response=<"+TRIM$(bstrResponse)+">")
   FUNCTION = bstrResponse
END FUNCTION
```

Comment: Here is the powerbasic code that makes the API call.

Comment: Why are you dumping all of those response headers into your requests?

Comment: Just an attempt to get it to work,  I used postman to run the same request and those headers were set.  The console of the web site had these errors.

Comment: The SSL certificate used to load resources from https://bam.nr-data.net will be distrusted in M70. Once distrusted, users will be prevented from loading these resources. See https://g.co/chrome/symantecpkicerts for more information.

Comment: Uncaught (in promise) DOMException: The play() request was interrupted by a call to pause()

Comment: pusher.min.js:8 Pusher : Error : {"type":"WebSocketError","error":{"type":"PusherError","data":{"code":null,"message":"Existing subscription to channel chat-requests-58a04170-a9e7-4e75-b722-699fd96d6649"}}}